# How do I invoke a custom function on sfGuard session time out in symfony

Tags: php, session, symfony1, session-timeout, sfguard

I am using sfGuard as the authentication plugin in my project. I want to invoke certain client side & server side scripts on session timeout. What is the best way I can do this.

Please help!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've been reading the `sfGuardSecurityUser` and it extends the `sfBasicSecurityUser` class, which handles user authentication, profile, credentials, etc.

So, I found a function in `sfBasicSecurityUser` that determines whether a users sessions is timed put called `isTimedOut`, and also `setTimedOut`.

If you want to do something when user's session times out, at least on server side, you should listen to the event that is throw when this happens. Check this method:

This could be found in the `symfony_core_root_dir/lib/user/sfBasicSecurityUser.class.php`

```
  public function initialize(sfEventDispatcher $dispatcher, sfStorage $storage, $options = array())
  {
    // initialize parent
    parent::initialize($dispatcher, $storage, $options);

    if (!array_key_exists('timeout', $this->options))
    {
      $this->options['timeout'] = 1800;
    }

    // force the max lifetime for session garbage collector to be greater than timeout
    if (ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') < $this->options['timeout'])
    {
      ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->options['timeout']);
    }

    // read data from storage
    $this->authenticated = $storage->read(self::AUTH_NAMESPACE);
    $this->credentials   = $storage->read(self::CREDENTIAL_NAMESPACE);
    $this->lastRequest   = $storage->read(self::LAST_REQUEST_NAMESPACE);

    if (null === $this->authenticated)
    {
      $this->authenticated = false;
      $this->credentials   = array();
    }
    else
    {
      // Automatic logout logged in user if no request within timeout parameter seconds
      $timeout = $this->options['timeout'];
      if (false !== $timeout && null !== $this->lastRequest && time() - $this->lastRequest >= $timeout)
      {
        if ($this->options['logging'])
        {
          $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'application.log', array('Automatic user logout due to timeout')));
        }

        $this->setTimedOut();
        $this->setAuthenticated(false);
      }
    }

    $this->lastRequest = time();
  }
```

For client side, you might start thinking about [HTML 5 and Javascript Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). The idea could be setting a worker when page loads, and telling him count till `session_time_out`, then redirecting to a login page or something.